# Using ipython magics in R jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I installed jupyter with `conda install jupyter` and am running a notebook with the r kernal installed from `conda create -n my-r-env -c r r-essentials`

I am running a notebook and want to run a bash command from a shell.

```
!echo "hi"
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:7: unexpected string constant
1: !echo "hi"
```

For comparison, in an notebook with a python kernel:

```
!echo "hi"
hi
```

Is there a way to set up R notebooks to have the same functionality as the ipython notebook with regards to bash commands (and maybe other magics)?

Comment: It looks like it is not possible: https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/244

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For just bash commands, it's possible to get system commands to work.  For example, in the IRkernel:

```
system("echo 'hi'", intern=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
'hi'
```

Or to see the first 5 lines of a file:

```
system("head -5 data/train.csv", intern=TRUE)
```

As IPython magics are available in the IPython kernel (but not in the IRkernel), I did a quick check if it was possible to access these using the `rPython` and `PythonInR` libraries.  However, the issue is that `get_ipython()` isn't visible to the Python code, so none of the following worked:

```
library("rPython")
rPython::python.exec("from IPython import get_ipython; get_ipython().run_cell_magic('writefile', 'test.txt', 'This is a test')")

library("PythonInR")
PythonInR::pyExec("from IPython import get_ipython; get_ipython().run_cell_magic('head -5 data/test.csv')")
```

Answer (score 5):

A cosmetic improvement to the output of `system` can be obtained by wrapping the call in `cat` and specify `'\n'` as the separator, which displays the output on separate lines instead of separated by whitespaces which is the default for character vectors. This is very useful for commands like `tree`, since the format of the output makes little sense unless separated by newlines.

Compare the following for a sample directory named `test`:

**Bash**

```
$ tree test
test
├── A1.tif
├── A2.tif
├── A3.tif
├── README
└── src
    ├── sample.R
    └── sample2.R

1 directory, 6 files
```

**R in Jupyter Notebook**

`system` only, difficult to comprehend output:

```
> system('tree test', intern=TRUE)

'test' '├── A1.tif' '├── A2.tif' '├── A3.tif' '├── README' '└── src' '    ├── sample.R' '    └── sample2.R' '' '1 directory, 6 files
```

`cat` + `system`, output looks like in bash:

```
> cat(system('tree test', intern=TRUE), sep='\n')

test
├── A1.tif
├── A2.tif
├── A3.tif
├── README
└── src
    ├── sample.R
    └── sample2.R

1 directory, 6 files
```

Note that for commands like `ls`, the above would introduce a newline where outputs are normally separated by a space in bash.

You can create a function to save you some typing:

```
> # "jupyter shell" function
> js <- function(shell_command){
>     cat(system(shell_command, intern=TRUE), sep='\n')
> }
>
> # brief syntax for shell commands
> js('tree test')
```